# Asp.Net Core Web API + Angular requests not working

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

i am developing web application using Angular and Asp.Net Core Web api and i  met up following issue: i get 400 error when sending requests. When i run my application using VS and IIS Express everything is ok, but when i deploy my app to IIS and use it directly by ip, the result of request is 400. You could see screenshots in attachment. Also i couldnt get acces directy by my api link, its states that angular router not find any path. Maybe this problem is related with angular routing? And i am using Swagger to interact with api.

**Visual studio + iis express**

[image]

**IIS**

[image]

Comment: have you set a breakpoint to see if you are able to hit the login controller at all? That is another thing, there needs to be more information in your post since this issue involves the API. Maybe putting some of your api code like controller methods and startup.cs so we can see some details to better assist you.

Comment: Yea, these are complex issues to resolve and it is difficult for us to help without more information. I would recommend that you take each step independently and see if you can narrow down the problem. And if the error is with the routing, then it doesn't have anything to do with the API. So narrowing down the issue is the first step.

Comment: If the issue *is* the router, my first guess would be the base path. By default, Angular is set up to serve the files from a base path. When you deploy to a server, you need to identify this base path: `ng build --base-href /folderName/` where folderName is the name of the folder on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my iis application pool hadnt rights to access sql database. C# were throwing an exception and in browser it was looking like there no related path.